# Как получить объект TreeViewitem из другого условия?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Есть код чтения файла в дерево. В нем есть 2 условия. В 1 создается объект TreeViewitem? Во 2 условии пытаюсь к нему обратиться получаю null. Как получить объект TreeViewitem из другого условия?

```
TreeViewItem section = new TreeViewItem();

public void mTreeView() {
    if (regexlink.IsMatch(linkparent)) {
        section = new TreeViewItem();
        section.Header = s.ToString();
    }

    if (regexlink2.IsMatch(linkparent)) {
        TreeViewItem d = new TreeViewItem();
        d.Header = "1";
        section.items.Add(d); // здесь null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TreeViewItem section;

public void mTreeView() {
        section = new TreeViewItem();
    if (regexlink.IsMatch(linkparent)) {
        section.Header = s.ToString();
    }

    if (regexlink2.IsMatch(linkparent)) {
        TreeViewItem d = new TreeViewItem();
        d.Header = "1";
        section.items.Add(d); // здесь не null
    }
}
```

Comment: Все равно добавление не работает из другого условия. Если условие вставлять в другое тогда условие не срабатывает.